Outlook ‍♂️?
what is the over all outlook on(GETH)GORELI ETHEREUM? AS THERE ARE MANY VERIFIED CONTRACTS AND WALLETS JUST LEFT ON THE BLOCKCHAIN. I think it would be useful to bring some or all of those contracts mainnet.

Please learn about Sepolia Testnet what it actually is. It's a testnet for developers, not ment to push all or even most of them to mainnet, apart from the fact that it would be a bad idea to send all tests that are carried out to the mainnet for a variety of reasons.

I am also on sepolia eth and i think the same thing about that network also because i see it has value. What do you mean by all of it?

Well I see what you mean by some because the mainnet circulating supply is 5.2 million on GETH.
